# setting ToolStripSplitButton.DropDownButtonWidth to 0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, statusbar, toolstrip

I want to use `ToolStripSplitButton` as a button only (no drop down menu) in my `StatusStrip`.

For this reason i want to not display the little arrow, but i can't do this.

Tried do this with setting `ToolStripSplitButton.DropDownButtonWidth` to 0, and it works successfull in windows 7 but not in windows xp.

how to get rid of the little arrow?

Answer (score 7):

Use the ToolStripDropDownButton instead of the ToolStripSplitButton.  The ToolStripDropDownButton has a property ShowDropDownArrow which will allow you to hide the drop down arrow.